# observable collection inside a class

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I am trying to implement an observable collection inside a class.

I am making a banking application to work this out.

I have theses classes

1. account
2. depositAccount
3. transaction

Inside the account class I created

```
private ObservableCollection<transaction> _accountTransactions;

public ObservableCollection<transaction> accountTransactions
{
    get { return _accountTransactions; }
    set { _accountTransactions = value; }
}

public account()
{
    _accountTransactions = new ObservableCollection<transaction>();
}
```

This means that every account loan or deposit will create an observable collection to store transactions in.

I create a new deposit account with an opening balance which is the first transaction and store the account in a list box called `lstDepositAccount`.

```
public depositAccount(double openingBalance)
{
    transaction newTransaction = new transaction();
    newTransaction.accountCredit = openingBalance;
    accountTransactions.Add(newTransaction);     
}
```

This works.

Now what I wanted to do was select an account from the list box of `lstDepositAccount` 
add a new transaction to the `ObservableCollection`

Also when an account is selected below I wanted to show the list of transactions in another list box called `lstDepositTransactions`.

when I create a new Deposit account it works but the first transaction is  populated but only (collection) is displayed.

In class transactions I overrode `ToString` method and still didn't help.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return " Transaction Date:" + transactionDate.ToString() + " " + "Transaction Amount: " + accountCredit.ToString();
}
```

here is the code for the 2 buttons to create an account and then create a new transaction

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double openingBalance = double.Parse(txtDepositOpiningBalance.Text);
    depositAccount newDepositAccount = new depositAccount(openingBalance);

    newDepositAccount.createdBy = txtDepositStaffMemberName.Text;
    newDepositAccount.accountNumber = int.Parse(txtDepositAccountNumber.Text);
    newDepositAccount.openingBalance = double.Parse(txtDepositOpiningBalance.Text);
    newDepositAccount.interestRate = double.Parse(txtDepositAccountInterestRate.Text);

    lstDepositAccount.Items.Add(newDepositAccount);
    lstSelectedAccountTransactions.Items.Add(newDepositAccount.accountTransactions);
}

private void btnNewTransaction_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    transaction newTransaction = new transaction();
    newTransaction.accountCredit = double.Parse(txtTransactionAmount.Text);
    newTransaction.transactionDate = (DateTime)dteTransactionDate.SelectedDate;

    lstSelectedAccountTransactions.Items.Add(newTransaction);

}
```

When I create an account the first transaction is displayed as (collection) it is only afterwards that the override to string method works.

Any ideas how I get to override the `ToString` method at the time I create a new account with the first transaction.

The only way I can see is to do the transaction separately rather than in one go at the start.

Sorry for the long post but I hope it is readable and understandable

Comment: WPF is NOT Winforms. Programmatically modifying the Items collection list is just asking for it. Why bother with ObservableCollection if you aren't binding??? The right way to do this is set it up with bound ItemsSource properties, it will work "automagically". This way is asking for trouble.

Comment: sorry I camel case everything. Thank you for that tip. So how would I bind the classes observable collection to the list box? 

I can't access the ObservableCollection during the WindowLoaded Event at all 



inside window loaded event 
and something like

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Well for starters, put your accountTransactions property inside an object that is set to the DataContext property of your window. That can be "this" for now, but it should be a seperate ViewModel class eventually. Then put `ItemsSource={Binding accountTransactions}` in your list box XAML. Now just modify accountTransactions like normal, the UI will automatically update! Note that this isn't really magic, ObservableCollection implements INotifyCollectionChanged which makes the whole thing work.

Comment: Also do some googling and research "WPF and MVVM" MSDN has some great tutorials to get you started down the right path.